# CSS divs stack vertically when scaling page smaller

Tags: html, css

I have a page that has two columns, like so:

|      1      | | 2 |

Column 1 has a width of 80% and column 2 has a width of 20% and is floated right.
Column one has a lot of wording & text, while column 2 only has a small form inside it.

I want column 2 to stack vertically above column 1 when the page is viewed on a smart phone, like so:

| 2 |

| 1 |

Any suggestions? I'm at a loss.

I'm trying to do this in WordPress, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you have a link to HTML or CSS?

Comment: Yep please post what you have so far so we can make the necessary amends

Comment: 2 possible alternatives: 1. Responsive design. 2. Give them `min-width` and when they reach it they'll automatically be in separate lines

Comment: I attempted to use this: http://jsfiddle.net/jPgWL/ and added the width percentages, but I made each column have a different class name, as they both had different attributes (mainly styling of borders and the float: right; for the 2nd column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a media query to target your device, and put the side column above your content column in the markup. `float: right;` the side column, and `float: left;` the content column to appear normally on desktop. Use a `media-query` to have them `clear: both;` and remove the float.

[image]

**CSS** (Updated with 100% wrapper)

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

article {
  background: #efefef;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}

aside {
  background: #ccc;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  aside, article {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <aside>Sidebar with form</aside>
  <article>Content content content ...</article>
</div>
```

[Codepen sketch.](http://cdpn.io/loDkK)

Comment: Doesn't sound quite right.. clearing both will prevent them from being side by side

Comment: Will it change anything if the .wrapper is 100%?

Comment: Instead of 960px? No, it won't. I have updated my code and sketch, and here's a screenshot.

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to 'accept' the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: One problem I'm having though; there seems to be some clipping on the right hand side. Any way I could possibly fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to set the styles for the screen size you are aiming for. Here is a site that lists many of them.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Inside of the media query set your styles for those divs.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .one, .two {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Set min-device-width and max-device-width to min-width and max-width if you want it to display responsive on desktop also.